# Custom transition colored menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, css-transitions

I have [this](http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links) link menu structure, with animated highlight color `onmouseover`, and I am interested to find a way to change the textcolor keeping the same transition effect instead of highlight underline like we have in [this](http://buzzworthystudio.com/) example (the pale grey text become white at `onmouseover`).

Honestly, I have no clue how to approach this, I only have identified the menu sequence in `html` and a few elements in `css` related to the color and transition - not worth to be mentioned, but it looks like there is much stuff behind maybe `javascript` code(?).

If there is someone that could give me more than a downvote, will be much appreciated. Thanks

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edge-ils-content-holder">
                <div class="edge-ils-content-table">
                    <div class="edge-ils-content-table-cell">
                                                                                    
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 1
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
                                                                                                                
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 2
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
                                                                                                                
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 3
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
                                                                                                                
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 4
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
                                                                                                                
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 5
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
                                                                                                                
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 6
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
                                                                                                                
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 7
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
                                                                                                                
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 8
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
                                                                                                                
                            <div class="edge-ils-item-content" style="font-size: 85px;line-height: 1.77em;font-weight: 800;text-align: left">
                                <a class="edge-ils-item-link" itemprop="url" target="_self" href="http://www.neuegrid.com/interactive-links" style="color:#0a0a0a;line-height: 1.77em">
                                    Link 9
                                                                                                                    <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-start" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                        <span class="edge-ils-item-link-shadow edge-box-shadow edge-end" style="background-color:rgba(218,229,0,0.92); height:50px;"></span>
                                                                    </a>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also take a look at [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) or  *[`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)(for infos)*

to switch from a color to another, a gradient image, background-size can be moved via background-position and transition:

```css
body {
  line-height: 5vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, gray, yellow, purple);/* see effects of method*/
}

a:after {
  content: ' mix-blend-mode + pseudo';
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  vertical-align: 0.75em
}

a:nth-child(even):after {
  content: ' background-clip';
}

a {
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  color: gray;
}

a:nth-child(odd):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, lime 50%, red 50%) 100% 0% no-repeat;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  /* not the best method */
  transition: 1s;
}

a:nth-child(even) {
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, lime 50%, red 50%) 100% 0% no-repeat;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-clip: text;
  transition: 1s;
}


/* move bg */

a:hover,
a:hover:before {
  background-position: 0% 0%
}
```

```html
<a href>link link link</a>
<a href>link link link</a>
<a href>link link</a>
<a href>break lines link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link link </a>
<a href>link link link</a>
<a href>link link link</a>
<a href>link link</a>
<a href>link link link link</a>
```

Comment: Totally forgot about using `mix-blend-mode` :). But, doesn't `mix-blend-mode` also use the same principle of using a source and destination overlapping to create a backdrop.

Comment: could be but it looks like this will change 100% the existing code. I don't have too much knowledge in coding but I suppose that the answer it's pretty near modifying the existing code. I suppose that the color transition should be applied on text element and remove the underline element but I don't know how to do it ... Thanks anyway

Comment: @AlokSingh mix-blend-mode is using here a pseudo to create the colors mixing indeed

Comment: @G-Cyr, is there any way to modify typo_'s code to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: @typo ?? for the background-clip method, there is nothing to touch on HTML, it is only about background. No pseudo is even required. mix-blend-mode is for infos and is not the best to use

Comment: @AlokSingh only the link is to be minded i think, the span can be removed or hidden, unless i totally misunderstood the desired effect ;)

Comment: @typo_ here is a codepen of the code, so you can play/edit  with it live . https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBOZVK

Comment: @G-Cyr I already played with the above but I'm not so sure how to apply in my case ... I have to discover what sequences are responsible with the effect in order to replace the underline color / transition with text `onmouseover` color / transition :)

Comment: @typo_ Can you make a screen of the desired effect. i am confused with the links provided. (half colored, or blending with image) ? Do you want the link to be painted from left to right black to yellow

Comment: @G-Cyr I am interested in text colored transition effect `onmouseover` not the previous screen (this is the [effect](https://i.imgur.com/M2PAUi5.jpg) ) I already have it but in [underline element](https://i.imgur.com/QuKl4jC.jpg) not in text ; Thanks,

Comment: Quote : "Do you want the link to be painted from left to right black to yellow " no, I am interested to replace the underline, coloring the text `onmouseover` from left to right ; In the example site [link](http://buzzworthystudio.com/) provided (not the source), the text is colored from gray pale to white `onmouseover`; just move the mouse through the links, forget about that half screen ... Thanks,

Comment: @typo_  Okay, background-clip + background-size seems fine i believe : demo with code separated https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OwOrYY

Comment: There should be also a text? All I can see is the two blocks which indeed are coloring but not the text ... Thank you,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176975/discussion-between-typo-and-g-cyr).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by placing another div on top of the the main div and then applying transition on to it.

```css
.main,
.cover {
  color: red;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:hover .cover {
  width: 100%;
}
.cover {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: blue;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">This is a text</div>
  <div class="cover">This is a text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty much the same; I suppose that the transition could be modified in order to go in the end to the right not back to the left. Unfortunately with my coding knowledge I am unable to modify my theme code in order to be functional ... As far as I can see there is a different structure and maybe more complex ... Will be too much if you modify my code and add css code extracted from my theme?

Comment: I tried finding the css code in your theme but couldn't find it, the furthest I reached was to be able to find some js code that worked upon hover. If you could find the code I might possibly be able to help.

Comment: Thank you; so there should be a js behind, I'll have a look.

Comment: [This](http://www.neuegrid.com/wp-includes/js/hoverIntent.min.js?ver=1.8.1) is what I was able to find, but don't think it is the one that performs the transition.